# What's the difference between fixed() and coll() for string matching?

Tags: r, stringr

Almost all the help files from the `stringr` package include this line

> Match a fixed string (i.e. by comparing only bytes), using fixed().
>   This is fast, but approximate. Generally, for matching human text,
>   you'll want coll() which respects character matching rules for the
>   specified locale.

The base R packages don't include an option for coll(), they only include an option for fixed(). But the base packages also has useBytes which is set to FALSE in the function, like in `grepl`.

Is fixed() the same thing as `fixed = TRUE, useBytes = TRUE` and coll() the same thing as `fixed = TRUE, useBytes = FALSE`? I'm new to stringr and I'm trying to find the equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coll()` is for a "collation search". Here's the exact example from `vignette("stringr")`

---

`coll(x)` looks for a match to x using human-language collation rules, and is particularly important if you want to do case insensitive matching. Collation rules differ around the world, so you’ll also need to supply a locale parameter.

```
i <- c("I", "İ", "i", "ı")
i
#> [1] "I" "İ" "i" "ı"

str_subset(i, coll("i", ignore_case = TRUE))
#> [1] "I" "i"
str_subset(i, coll("i", ignore_case = TRUE, locale = "tr"))
#> [1] "İ" "i"
```

The downside of `coll()` is speed. Because the rules for recognising which characters are the same are complicated, `coll()` is relatively slow compared to `regex()` and `fixed()`. Note that when both `fixed()` and `regex()` have `ignore_case arguments`, they perform a much simpler comparison than `coll()`

---

So basically `coll()` uses the information from a given locale to know what characters basically mean the same and allows them to match each other even though technically they are different characters.

Comment: It looks like coll() helps to match letters that represent the same letter, but may be formatted in different ways (in different bytes?). Are there any cases wheer coll() matches a letter with a different letter, case excluded?

Comment: Here's the [ICU collator user guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation), linked from `?stringi::stri_opts_collator`. From their examples, *'letters "v" and "w" are two different letters according to English. However, "v" and "w" are traditionally considered variant forms of the same letter in Swedish.'* So if your locale is Swedish, then yes (depending on your definition of "different").